# Android Sceneform Plane Detection and their angles

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I am trying to develop an Android app which is trying to draw a perfect line directly in front of me. My reference point is my phone, which means that the line has to parallel to my phone's left side.

I have following issues:

- I am using Sceneform, so there is no "onSurfaceCreated" callback.(?)
- I assume that the white-dots shows the surface. But, then I think if there is a detected surface then I can place a Shape on it. But is can not happen sometimes. And sometimes, I can place a Shape even if there are no visible white-dots.
- When I try to draw a line between the points (0,0,0) to (1,0,0), it is not always parallel to the left side of my phone. I assume that the reason of this is related with the following fact :

  - angle between the left-bottom corner of the detected surface and the left-top corner is not zero. (If we consider the coordinate system as follows : phone's left side is y-axis, bottom is the x-axis.)And this angle changes each time I reopen the app.

These are more **theory** questions than the implementation. So, I need someone to prove or disprove, or give me guideline.

Answer (score 1):

1) There isn't method like onSurfaceCreated.

2) Not all the detected planes are covered with white-dots. Is is intended because if all the detected planes are rendered with white-dots, it would confuse the users

3) When you talk about the points(0,0,0) and (1,0,0), is it world position or local position? Whether it is world position or local position, you can not draw a line parallel to your left side of phone in the way you approach.